# Paragraph & formatting marks similar to MS Word option

Tags: formatting, paragraphs

Is there a way to show/hide the paragraph and other formatting in LaTeX as with Word Show/Hide ¶ option.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really make any sense: (La)TeX doesn't use any 'hidden' data, all of your source is there for you to see.

Comment: @JosephWright I want to show where paragraphs/newline break and   breaking and nonbreaking spaces in the output document (pdf) not the source.

Comment: What do you want `TeX` to do if the  pilcrow (backwards 'p' symbol) doesn't fit on the end of a line of text?

Comment: @IanThompson That can be handled presumably using `\rlap` (though the fact that `\par` tokens appear in all sorts of places is more of an issue).

Comment: @IanThompson preferably stay on same line.